# How to count the number of selected lines in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

Are the number of selected lines shown in the Status Bar of Intellij Idea? ( The 'number of characters' selected count is shown if the selection includes words)

Comment: Please vote http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123378

Answer (score 1):

Feature mentioned in the comments is now available.

Right click on the status bar, select "Line column count", see image:
[image]

Then you have in the status bar the count of selected lines (it's called line breaks when you select something):
[image]